# Resources to Learn DynamoDB Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am a learning by hands-on or video person. Are there any resources out there to learn complex querying in DynamoDB for instance querying in deeply nested maps? I want to have a practice and it will help me design DynamoDBs better.

The docs are hard to follow for queries/filter.

Any resources will help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some great resources that I gathered available online for you to learn DynamoDB:

- [Best Practices for Designing and Architecting with DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices.html)
- [alexdebrie/awesome-dynamodb](https://github.com/alexdebrie/awesome-dynamodb)
- [Build with DynamoDB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3S1OnDqWl4&list=PLn7ZNwOo3cY34qsR-O6zypBQF9pLUqoyl)
- [Serverless Stack](https://serverless-stack.com/) (Start your first fully serverless project)
- [AWS DynamoDB Guides - Everything you need to know about DynamoDB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XvD2FrS5yYM&list=PL9nWRykSBSFi5QD8ssI0W5odL9S0309E2)
- [AWS DynamoDB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0eMG4YIbvY&list=PLvmxnsCyoh65lBHmg9TTPJg3nK4l50oxv)
- [The DynamoDB Book](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RE5qFipGn7c&list=PLNjt4IpUlQLieAf8YE4bjN7kgwntsfW_B)

Comment: [AWS re:Invent 2019: Data modeling with Amazon DynamoDB (CMY304) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIQVJqiSUkE&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yeah, this is included in the first Alex's Github repo.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the very comprehensive list! Which would you recommend to really train on querying specifically or nested filter expressions?

Comment: @JiaYing I recommend official doc and the reinvent talks. They dive pretty deeply into design and query.